# How I can get siteAccountId from yodlee fastlink once added account

Tags: java, iframe, yodlee

I am trying to get siteAccountId and siteId from yodlee fastlink. I am following below process and no idea how I can get/read siteAccountId and siteId from yodlee end.

1. Successfully generated fastlink url for link account as per yodlee
   documentation in loaded in to a iframe.
2. The page is successfully loaded and I am able to see the yodlee link page with in iframe.
3. Linked a Dagbank account by using yodlee dummy accounts and the account is successfully added.
4. How I can get siteAccountId and siteId from my client or API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [getAllSiteAccounts](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) API and from the response of this API you can get the siteAccountID based on the "DisplayName" and the value from "created" which will tell you when it was created incase you have same site added twice.

So for the DAGBank which you linked , after calling the above API search for DAGBank and get the SiteAccountID and incase you have two DAGBanks added check the "created" field as well.

Comment: Great, Thanks @Shreyans. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Shreyans, I tried and able to get aiteAccountId based on "Display Name" but I scaring about accuracy when user adding two more accounts at same time. Is there any other ways to identify the add/link correct account based on account number?